# AWS MFA Issue Please verify your MFA serial number is valid and associated with this user

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-factor-authentication

Been using https://github.com/broamski/aws-mfa to handle MFA for AWS with much success. I have three users who get the following error when trying to use it:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: MultiFactorAuthentication failed, unable to validate MFA code.  Please verify your MFA serial number is valid and associated with this user.`

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot? I have 20+ users that are just fine; I'm at the end of my rope on what these three users are doing different. I've verified that they didn't do a bad copy-pasta into their credentials file.

Comment: It sounds like the MFA serial number associated with the user is incorrect. Check their IAM User record and verify the ID against the code used on their MFA device.

Comment: That ended up being the actual issue. Their key was listed as “never used” and a refresh of their key fixed it

Comment: This can also happen if username is mis-spelt (including upper/lower case)

Comment: Since AWS introduced a Device Name for your Virtual MFA Device, this can cause confusion because previously the MFA serial would be; `arn:aws:iam::$ACCOUNT-NUMBER:mfa/$USER` & now it will be `arn:aws:iam::$ACCOUNT-NUMBER:mfa/$DEVICE-NAME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get this if you haven't specified a profile (either inline or as an env variable). You don't need to delete your default profile, if a named profile is not specified in the context then it uses the default profile.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE=user1
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and resolved it by modifying `~/.aws/config`. No need to remove the default profile.

As @paulg mentioned in the comments, it should be `arn:aws:iam::$ACCOUNT-NUMBER:mfa/$DEVICE-NAME` instead of user name.

PS: The device name is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete the default profile from your AWS machine, in the following files:

- ~/.aws/credentials
- ~/.aws/config

It worked for me.

Comment: This works! That error is so unintuitive, it does not clarify that the `aws configure` does not the other command you run i.e. `aws sts get-session-token` and that is why you get cannot authorise.